# Django : translation not found only during tests

Tags: django, testing, translation, fixture

I'm doing functional tests (Selenium) on my django app, and I want to include some fixtures.
So first, I tried to load fixtures using manage.py:

```
./manage.py dumpdata > db.json
./manage.py loaddata db.json
```

No errors, I decided to use this data for my tests:

```
class FrontTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    fixtures = ['db.json']
```

But when I ran my test:

```
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/srv/app/db.json': EventBlock has no field named 'content_fr'
```

Have you ever get this error ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to update (re-create) the fixture if you changed your model -> `EventBlock has no field named 'content_fr'`. Does `EventBlock` model have a  `content_fr` field?

Comment: I know, but I didn't change model. And yes it does.